# Fourier transform and heat equation on quarter plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fourier-transform, heat-equation

Question:
Consider $u_t = k(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$, x, y > 0
subject to the boundary conditions

u(0, y, t) = 0 and $u_y(x,0,t) = 0$ and initial condtion

u(x, y, 0) = f(x, y).

If we would have $-\infty < x < \infty$ and $-\infty < y < \infty$, I would try the double Fourier transform, but since it is given that x, y > 0, I have no idea what to do.

Edit: I thought, maybe I should use a Fourier sine transform in x, a Fourier cosine transform in y or both? But I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: Couldn't you just extend $f(x,y)=0\text{  }\forall \text{  }x<0 \text{ or } y<0$?

Comment: Your boundary condition is zero, just expand the domain to include negative reals and make everything zero there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary condition is automatically satisfied if $u$ is defined on the entire plane as being  odd in $x$ and even in $y$. So try first extending $f$ to the entire plane to have appropriate symmetries.